# java generics: can't create a simple print array method

Tags: java, arrays, generics, printing

So i keep on getting an error on the next code. And I have no idea what i'm doing wrong.
The error is The method printArray(T[]) in the type main is not applicable for the arguments (int[])

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Oefening1 oef = new Oefening1();
        int[] integerArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
        printArray(integerArray);
    }

    public static <T> void printArray(T[] arr){
        for(T t: arr){
           System.out.print(t + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to generics, Java makes a difference between primitive types and types derived from `java.lang.Object`. Only non-primitive types can be used as arguments of generic methods. Since `int` is not generic, `printArray<T>` does not apply to it.

You can fix it by providing an overload for `int`, or by making `integerArray` an `Integer[]`:

```
Integer[] integerArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
printArray(integerArray);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/aiM59H)

The reason this works is that `Integer` wraps `int` in an object suitable for passing to generics. However, this takes a lot of help from Java compiler, because when you write `{1,2,3,4,5}` it gets translated to  `{Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(2), Integer.valueOf(3), Integer.valueOf(4), Integer.valueOf(5)}` behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using primitive type of the data type. If you use Integer[] integerArray = {1,2,3,4,5}; instead of int[] integerArray = {1,2,3,4,5};. It should work.